# Batch script for copying files based on name

Tags: batch-file, copy, compare, filenames

Basically I want to write a little batch script that does the following - I have two folders, A and B... A has 10 files and B has 100. I want to compare the names of the files in each folder and if any in B have the same name as in A, then to copy them to folder A and overwrite the original file.

I was trying to start off by doing a "for" command on folder A but then I would have to follow that with an IF to compare the filenames which I have no idea how to express correctly

```
    for /r "C:\folderA" %%a in (*.filetype) do (...)
```

Sry but I am useless with batch scripting. I found a couple of threads covering similar questions, but rly didn't follow the answers enough to help.

Is this difficult? The other threads comparing two filenames looked kinda complicated.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Have you tried `RoboCopy` with `/XL`? or `XCopy` with `/U`?

Comment: Read the whole `help for` especially the part with the `~` modifiers. Also the nearly forgotten `help replace` still exists

Comment: ...this is what happens if I take my time to answer the question only to find out it was already answered in comments :-) Won't delete the answer though as it is more verbose.

Comment: @JackWhite a question with an answer in a comment is still in the "unanswered queue". So yes, keep your answer (but correct the source/destination order)

Comment: Ok, corrected source/destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
xcopy /s /u /y /i /r /c "C:\folderB\*.filetype" "C:\folderA"
```

- `/s` copies folders and subfolders
- `/u` copies only file that pre-exist in both folders
- `/y` suppresses prompts on overwriting files
- `/i` tells xcopy that destination is a folder
- `/r` ignores `READONLY` attribute just in case (this is optional)
- `/c` continues copying even if errors occur (this is optional)

More information on xcopy can be found [here](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) (or `xcopy /?`)

If that does not work for you then something like this should do:

```
for /r "C:\folderA" %%a in (*.filetype) do if exist "C:\folderB\%%~nxa" copy /y "C:\folderB\%%~nxa" "C:\folderA\%%~nxa"
```

Here is what it does:

- `if exist` checks if a file exists

  - the path it checks is composed from `folderA` path and name and extension of the file found in `folderB`
- `copy /y` copies file overwriting existing one

  - from original file found in `folderB`
  - to similar-named file found in `folderA`

`%%~dpnxa` syntax goes like this:

- `%%SOMETHINGa` means this is a for-loop variable
- `~` suppresses double quotes around file names (we will provide our own ones)
- `d` is for disk (`c:`)
- `p` is for path to containing folder (`\folderA\`)
- `n` is for name of the file (i.e. `readme`)
- `x` is for extension (i.e. `.txt`)

You can mix and match those as you like. More info is [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) or try `for /?`

If logic needs to be more complicated I suggest either using `(` `)` brackets + [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) or [`call :label`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (`call /?`)

UPDATE: Corrected mixup of `FolderA` and `FolderB`

Comment: Is the requirement not that `folderB`=source and `folderA`=destination?

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! So I tried everything you suggested. The first command using xcopy didn't work the first time I tried it giving an error like "cannot perform cyclic copy" - I just tried it again to get the exact error back and it worked the second time... so I dunno what I did differently the second time.

The second method worked fine too except was copying from folderA to folderB, so I simply had to reverse everything for it to work, But either way both are great. Thank you ever so much Jack, really appreciated!

Comment: You would only get a cyclic copy error if the destination is a sub folder of the source

Comment: Sorry, I misread and written code to copy from A -> B. I have corrected the code. It may not work if folder A is subfolder of folder B or vice versa. If that is really the case please elaborate more on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its perfect, worked a charm. Tbh the location of the folders isn't such an issue as I can move them if needed, normally I just put them somewhere near the C:\ so I don't have to type in long paths. So have just been both folder together in the same dir.