# Modification required to work on all subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I just need the following batch file to work on all directories and subdirectories down the main directory tree.

```
for /r "C:\folderA" %%a in (*.filetype) do if exist "C:\folderB\%%~nxa" copy /y "C:\folderB\%%~nxa" "C:\folderA\%%~nxa"
```

It overwrites files in the destination directory, `C:\folderA`, with files from the source directory, `C:\folderB`, once those files' names are matched.

This batch works only on one level directory and can be found at: [Batch script for copying files based on name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350200/batch-script-for-copying-files-based-on-name).

Comment: Hint: what does  `%%~nxa` stand for?

Comment: You are checking the presence of files in the whole tree `C:\folderA` against files in the flat folder `C:\folderB` and in the copy use flat `C:\folderA` as the destination (missing subfolders included in %%a) So it's unclear if you want to compare whole trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Stephan triggered it for me. 
Just replaced `"C:\folderA\%%~nxa"` with `"%%~a"` and it worked fine.
Thanks everybody.